# React JS Yup + Formik trigger function with every validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I'm using `Formik` with `Yup` for validation, using the `useFormik() hook`, like this:

```
const formik = useFormik({
     initialValues,
     validationSchema: yup.object({
          password: yup
             .string()
             .required('Please enter a password ')
             .matches(/[a-z]/, ONE_LETTER_MESSAGE)
             .matches(/\d/, ONE_NUMBER_MESSAGE)
             .matches(/[A-Z]/, CAPITAL_LETTER_MESSAGE)
             .matches(/[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?~]/, SPECIAL_CHAR_MESSAGE)
             .min(18, EIGHTEEN_CHARS_MESSAGE),
     }),
     onSubmit: handleOnSubmit,
});
```

I want to keep track of the state of the validations performed by `yup` - to display in a separate list if each of that validation like .matches(/\d/, ONE_NUMBER_MESSAGE) etc is validated or not so that the user can know which one of them has been satisfied or not.

Is it possible to trigger a function when the `.matches(/\d/, ONE_NUMBER_MESSAGE)`, `.matches(/[A-Z]/, CAPITAL_LETTER_MESSAGE)` etc function are called in the validation process?

Comment: I think we need to know about why you need to do this to help a bit more (your use case). Typically, youd allow the schema to evaluate unimpeded and then respond to specific errors by checking the formik error state -- but it kinda depends.

Comment: @AdamThomas I want to display in a list if each of that validation like `.matches(/\d/, ONE_NUMBER_MESSAGE)` etc is validated or not so that the user can know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your comment on your original question, I gather you need to display the error to the user.

When the schema is run, Formik takes the results of that schema and it puts the resulting errors (if there are any) into the `errors` state inside Formik.

You should be able to access the error for the `password` field by doing this in render -- which will return the user-friendly string error you defined in the schema:

```
formik.errors.password
```

If you really want to do more than display (run it through it function) you could create a `useEffect` hook that has this in the `deps` array.